# Flex element includein

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

In Flex, we can assign state to an element via this:

```
<s:Button id="mybtn" includeIn="mystate" label="button label"/>
```

How can we do the `includeIn` with ActionScript?

Thank you.

Comment: use the button id to use the includeInLayout element in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

States are an MXML concept, not an AS concept. In AS you have to write your own logic in the override function set currentState.

```
override public function set currentState(value:String):void
{
  super.currentState = value;
  //write your logic for states
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `includeIn` pseudo-attribute only exists in the MXML language. I call it a pseudo-attribute because it does not map to a property or a style (of the Button class in your example).

Instead it is a shorthand notation of the old mx [AddItems](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/states/AddItems.html) tag. In that syntax your example would look something like this:

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="normal"/>
    <mx:State name="mystate">
        <mx:AddItems items="{mybtn}"/>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>

<mx:Button id="mybtn"/>
```

I mention this, because the ActionScript code that is generated for `includeIn` is very similar. This is what it looks like:

```
states = [
    new State ({
        name: "normal",
        overrides: []
    }),
    new State ({
        name: "mystate",
        overrides: [
          new AddItems().initializeFromObject({
            itemsFactory: _TestFlex_Button1_factory,
            destination: null,
            position: "first"
          })
        ]
    })
];
```

The difference is that it uses a factory to instantiate the Button.
Note that if you're interested in the ActionScript code that is generated from MXML code, you can have a look at it simply by passing the `keep-generated-actionscript` flag to the compiler (see [mxmlc compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)).

Of course if you really want to 'manually' write that logic (I wouldn't), it may be easier to override [setCurrentState()](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/core/UIComponent.html#setCurrentState%28%29) or listen for the [CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/events/StateChangeEvent.html#CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE) event, and call `addElement()` or `removeElement()` depending on the value of `currentState`.