# How do Flex Actionscript States work under the covers?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, state

So I used to program Flex applications for years. I have used States in Flex and wanted to see about porting them over to another language. The other language has a run loop so that isn't my concern.

My question is: Does anyone know how the States were programmed in Flex? I am assuming they were added far up the object heirarchy, but what design pattern was used to implement them?  I assume that on each iteration through the run loop a notification or event is sent for each class to broadcast its STATE or for each class to ask itself what STATE should I be in.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Flex is open source; so go ahead and open up the source to take a look.  If you're really adventurous; pull up the Flextras Calendar code (in GitHub) where I implemented the Calendar states in pure ActionScript.

Comment: I wrote this last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604433/flex-element-includein/20610359#20610359. Could be a starting point to know where to look. @Reboog711 I'm curious: why did you do that?

Comment: @RIAstar Because all the Flex Framework components were built in ActionScript; so if you want to build a business selling "equal quality" components it is best to follow the conventions.  The state changes themselves were a bit tedious, but no big deal.  Getting state transitions to work turned out to be very time consuming proposition [then a point release of the Flex Framework broke all that code]

Comment: @Reboog711 I understand. I made some components of my own (never commercial though) and I usually delegate the state management to the skin so it can be handled with mxml. But of course a calendar component is quite a big beast. I imagine it can get complicated, especially since I suspect you created it in the Flex 3 days (before the Spark architecture).

Comment: @RIAstar Yes, the first version of my Calendar was built on 3.2 if memory serves me. I never converted it to a Spark component.